# History of italicising variables and mathematical formatting in general

Tags: notation

In the modern day, especially with the advent of $\mathrm\TeX$, it is common practice to italicise variables. This can be seen as far back as Hann, J. ([1850](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Examples_on_the_Integral_Calculus/bTk7AQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0)). *Examples on the Integral Calculus*. What's the oldest example of this and when did it become standard?

Answer (score 15):

In another answer of mine, we see an image of
["Disquisitiones generales circa superficies curvas"](https://archive.org/details/disquisitionesg00gausgoog/page/n30/mode/2up) from 1828 by C.F. Gauss.

[image: Gauss]

Note that already here the mathematical letters are set in italic.  (But the operator $\mathrm{d}$ for derivatives is in roman.) I expect this practice goes back much further than 1828.

---

Another. *Institutiones Calculus Differentialis*, L. Euler, 1787
[image: Euler]

Here is *Analyse des Infiniment Petits*, l'Hospital, 1696
[image: lhospital]
Even then, using italic.  Note the $d$ for differentials is italic as well.

Comment: Isn't it C.F.Gauss? His first name is Carl or "Caroli" in Latin.

Comment: I think you are right.  "Karl" can also be found on the internet, but "Carl" is most often used.

Answer (score 15):

Rene Descartes's *La Géométrie* of 1637 uses the same typographic convention used today in France: in equations, lower case letters  are set in italics but capital letters are set in upright text.  This can be seen on the third
[page](https://diglib.hab.de/drucke/64-25-quod-1/start.htm?image=00385)
of the book.  It can also be seen in  the 1925 bilingual [edition](http://explore.bl.uk/primo_library/libweb/action/dlSearch.do?vid=BLVU1&institution=BL&search_scope=LSCOP-ALL&query=any,contains,descartes+geometrie%20smith&tab=local_tab) by D. E. Smith and M. L. Latham, with a facsimile of the original and translation on facing pages. (Reprinted in 1954 by [Dover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486600688).)

The web page https://debart.pagesperso-orange.fr/geometrie/index.html#oeuvre
gives the same facsimile pages, as best as I can tell.